# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/xvfb-run'

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, xvfb

I'm getting this error while running Django test in mac machine,

Error:

```
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 696, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1540, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/xvfb-run'
```

> How can install xvfb-run on MAC Machine?

I have also installed XQuartz and add the path, But problem not solved.

Comment: It seems that something is trying to find xvfb-run in /usr/bin, so you wouldn't need to add it to the path. So you need to find which module is expecting xvfb-run to be in /usr/bin.

Comment: `__So you need to find which module is expecting xvfb-run to be in /usr/bin__` I've tried it but unable to find it.